# Performance variations with int.CompareTo

Tags: c#, .net

[Edit 3...]

Bogus: my original code used loops, which corrupted the tests. It appears to be obvious with the code below ... NOT a "huge" difference after all.

I originally thought I saw a big difference in performance between these two forms of CompareTo:

```
int[] arr;
int j, comp;

comp = j.CompareTo(arr[j]);
comp = arr[j].CompareTo(j);
```

... Just reversed versions of "the same" comparison! --- I also tried the same using a List instead of Array.

My original code introduced problems in the test by loading in a loop differently. The adjusted test is below; and it does not show the "huge" difference I thought i saw.

I also believed the List introduced boxing and unboxing ... I will examine the IL code to learn that.

There is still a marginal difference between the two forms in the first pair, and the two forms in the second pair; which might be of a little interest since the code is quite similar yet produces different IL output.

In Stopwatch ticks, on my machine I get:

```
int.CompareTo(List<int>[]) (Unboxing?)
337095

List<int>[].CompareTo(int) (Boxing?)
375601

int.CompareTo(Array<int>[])
157093

Array<int>[].CompareTo(int)
135420
```

New code:

```
static void Main() {
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    int iterations = 100000000;
    int comp = 0, accessIndex = 50, arg = 0;
    List<int> list = new List<int>(100);
    int[] arr = new int[100];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < 100; i+=2, j++) {
        list.Add(i);
        arr[j] = i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("int.CompareTo(List<int>[]) (Unboxing?)");
    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        comp = arg.CompareTo(list[accessIndex]);
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("List<int>[].CompareTo(int) (Boxing?)");
    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        comp = list[accessIndex].CompareTo(arg);
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("int.CompareTo(Array<int>[])");
    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        comp = arg.CompareTo(arr[accessIndex]);
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Array<int>[].CompareTo(int)");
    stopwatch.Reset();
    stopwatch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        comp = arr[accessIndex].CompareTo(arg);
    }
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedTicks);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

If you are still reading: the differences in the IL code in the last pair (with the Array) are only in the top of the loop:

"int.CompareTo(Array[])" ==

```
// loop start (head: IL_0115)
IL_0103: ldloca.s comp
IL_0105: ldloc.s arr
IL_0107: ldloc.3
IL_0108: ldelem.i4
IL_0109: call instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Int32::CompareTo(int32)
```

"Array[].CompareTo(int)" ==

```
// loop start (head: IL_0160)
IL_014b: ldloc.s arr
IL_014d: ldloc.3
IL_014e: ldelema [mscorlib]System.Int32
IL_0153: ldloc.2
IL_0154: call instance int32 [mscorlib]System.Int32::CompareTo(int32)
```

And in the List versions, I do NOT see any boxing in the IL!

Comment: Please put the units (ticks per 10 million operations) on the numbers.  Otherwise the results are easily confused with throughput (operations per second).

Comment: Have you executed the code on Release without VS (launching the exe from cmd for example) ; results can be really different depending on that. Also you should try to decompile the code and have a look at the IL (or just paste it in the post to avoid people to do it themselves) there should be info on what is really going on

Comment: Assuming you are testing Release without the debugger attached one issue is that you are bounds checking the array's loops against the list's Count. I'm pretty sure this is going to trash the JITs ability to elide bounds checks and possibly the processor cache.

Comment: Thanks folks: the units are Stopwatch ticks. But: I am examining the IL code. I think the error lies in my loops ... One version loads values and the other loads pointers. I will try an edit to the code. (Sorry if I posted prematurely.)

Comment: Considering that a accessing a list involves accessing an internal array, it must at the very least (100% efficiency) take more time than accessing an array and would generally be expected to take longer.

Comment: For the record there is no boxing occurring in any of the code you've provided.  I'm not sure why you think there is.

Comment: Assuming it is inlined, `CompareTo` should not result in more than 1 or 2 instructions once optimized. There should not be a huge variance.

Comment: Please consolidate the various [Edit]s into a single, coherent question. Right now it's getting more and more difficult to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Kyle: I believe you are right! I assumed that the CompareTo invocation on the list somehow introduces boxing; but the IL does not show any. The performance difference (compared to the array) seems to be in the virtual call only ...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Bogus!

My original code test was the problem ... in the loops I used. The edited code shows pretty consistent results ... and the IL looks clear.